# error: <anonymous> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onBitmapFailed(Exception,Drawable) in Target

Tags: java, android, picasso

i am trying to implement picasso into my android app and i am getting error.

error on target() -> class 'anonymous class derived from the target' must be declare abstract or implement abstract method onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) in target.

error on onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) -> Method does not override  method from its superclass.

```
private Target loadtarget;

public void loadBitmap(String url) {

    if (loadtarget == null) loadtarget = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            tempBmp=bitmap;
            new HomeScreenOperation().execute("");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };
    Picasso.get().load(url).into(loadtarget);
}
```

Comment: I have not worked with android in a long time and don't remember the import strategy, but this sounds a lot, like the Drawable class you import is not the Drawable class expected by this abstract method's signature. Try to validate the package names (of the Drawable expected, and the drawable you import).

Comment: Do you have your own `Drawable` class, that you're inadvertently using, instead of the one that's used in the interface?

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed that the title of your question doesn't match the error message in the text.  Which one is correct?  If the title is correct, then maybe all you have to do is add a parameter of type `Exception` to your declaration of `onBitmapFailed`.

Comment: getting title message in compiler. and description error message are displayed on code mouse hover. how to add exception?

Comment: So what happens if you add an initial parameter of type `Exception` to `onBitmapFailed`? (ie `public void onBitmapFailed(Exception myException, Drawable errorDrawable) {` )?

Comment: OMG! thank you so much. error gone. i am new in android and java. thank you so much for help